# Discord.py only send a message to one person

Tags: discord.py

I am making a discord bot in python and I want it to send a message to only the person who typed in a command without sending it to anyone else.
Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please do include your code, approaches and errors you face. You may also take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -1):

See here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#converters

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command(name='your_command')
async def DM(user: discord.User, message="Hi"):
    await user.send(message)
```

Comment: Please do not add an answer to a question that has no real semblance of inquiry, even if it is kindly meant, thank you!